# Quicksort Empirical Analysis StackOverflowError

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, quicksort

I'm attempting to perform an analysis on Quicksort but I'm running into an inconsistent StackOverflowError. I believe it's probably due to unbound recursion with higher data sets but I can't figure out how to fix it. My partition might also be off but debugging hasn't worked out too well for me.

The data set I'm using is a set of randomly generated int arrays of size 10,000 using a pivot (arr[0])

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at AlgorithmTiming.quickSort(AlgorithmTiming.java:78)
    at AlgorithmTiming.quickSort(AlgorithmTiming.java:82)

private int[] quickSort(int[] arr, int low, int high, int pivotType){

    if (low < high)
    {
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[pi] is
        now at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high, pivotType);

        // Recursively sort elements before
        // partition and after partition
        quickSort(arr, low, pi-1, pivotType);
        quickSort(arr, pi+1, high, pivotType);
    }
    return arr;
}
private int partition(int arr[], int low, int high, int pivotType)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int pivot = arr[0]; //Default Pivot
    if(pivotType == 2) pivot = arr[0] + arr[arr.length / 2] + arr[arr.length-1]; //Median Pivot
    else if(pivotType == 3) pivot = arr[rand.nextInt(arr.length)]; //Random Pivot

    int i = (low-1); // index of smaller element
    for (int j=low; j<=high-1; j++)
    {
        // If current element is smaller than or
        // equal to pivot
        if (arr[j] <= pivot)
        {
            i++;
            // swap arr[i] and arr[j]
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    // swap arr[i+1] and arr[high] (or pivot)
    int temp = arr[i+1];
    arr[i+1] = arr[high];
    arr[high] = temp;

    return i+1;
}
```

Comment: Please post the whole error message and the dataset you use. Best: post a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: updated, should be easier to read now.

Comment: But there is still no MCVE!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to attempt to debug your code.  (For a start, you did not provide an MCVE ... or even a stacktrace.)

However, consider this:

- Quicksort is a recursive algorithm that works by "dividing" the sorting problem into two smaller sorting problems until the problems are trivial.  This is the partitioning step.
- If you are sorting N elements and you *correctly* divide the sort problems in half each time, then you will only need to log<sub>2</sub>N (or less) divisions to get down to the (trivial) problem of sorting one element.

And then from the Java perspective:

- A StackOverflowError means that your recursion has gotten too deep.

So ... **without looking at the code** ... it is almost a safe bet that the problem is in the way that you have implemented the partitioning.  That's where you should focus your attention.

I would suggest the following:

- Eyeball the code to see if you can figure out why the partitioning isn't choosing correct partition boundaries; i.e. low, pi, and hi.
- Use a debugger to see what the code is *doing*.
- Add traceprints to see what the values of low, pi, and hi are, and how they change as the algorithm progresses.

---

The other thing to note is that classic quicksort has an edge case where the choice of partition can lead to O(N<sup>2</sup>) rather than O(NlogN) behavior; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Worst-case_analysis.  This corresponds to the case where sorting N elements requires N-deep recursion.  That will lead to `StackOverflowError` problems in Java, for large enough N.